# Blackberry Maps - Detect click in RichMapField?

Tags: blackberry, maps, blackberry-jde

I'm getting my richmapfield from a factory like so:

```
map = MapFactory.getInstance().generateRichMapField();
```

My question is how do I detect clicks/swipes etc on a RichMapField?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it is not possible, because RichMapField is final class and cannot be extended. And its methods cannot be overriden.